# Need some help in fixing the Spark streaming dependency (Scala sbt)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-streaming

I am trying to run basic spark streaming example on my machine using IntelliJ, but I am unable to resolve the dependency issues. 
Please help me in fixing it.

```
name := "demoSpark"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark"% "spark-core_2.11"%"2.1.0",
                              "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "2.1.0",
                              "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.1.0",
                              "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.10" % "2.1.0"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least, all the dependencies must use the same version of Scala, not a mix of 2.10 and 2.11. You can use %% symbol in sbt to ensure the right version is selected (the one you specified in scalaVersion).

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.0"
)
```